# how to get time zone of city or country in javascript

Tags: javascript

I use `getTimezoneOffset()` to get the offset in minutes for a given date object. Is is possible to use javascript to get timezone offset of a city or a country?

for example:

```
var offset = getCityOffset("Miami"); // returns -240
```

Comment: JavaScript knows nothing about `"Miami"`..

Comment: Also it's a method of the `Date` object.

Comment: use moment.js here

Comment: how about using coordinates and gMaps Api: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro#Introduction

Answer (score 15):

No, there is nothing built-in to javascript which allows you to get the number of minutes to offset for specific time zones/cities.

[`getTimeZoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) works for the *current browser's settings*

[MomentJS Timezone extensions](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) has some of this sort of functionality, which is of course reliant on the MomentJS library.

If you have access to Lat/Long values, then google provide [a timezone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro#Introduction)

Comment: Looks like there's an angry serial downvoter around today. That's a good answer.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to answer this question for Node.js using TypeScript (please remove the types if you want to use with plan JavaScript). For that, we will need 2 NPM packages.

- [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)
- [city-timezones](https://github.com/kevinroberts/city-timezones)

Disclaimer: **Timezones are COMPLEX. Not all timezones are 1 hour apart and some daylight saving time settings are weird with, for example, 15 minutes difference instead of the standard 60 minutes. This is a naive implementation that suited my use case. Use with discretion**.

Code:

```
import * as cityTimeZones from "city-timezones";
import * as moment from "moment-timezone";

/**
 * Returns the UTC offset for the given timezone
 * @param timezone Example: America/New_York
 */
export function getNormalizedUtcOffset(timezone: string): number | null {
  const momentTimezone = moment.tz(timezone);
  if (!momentTimezone) {
    return null;
  }
  let offset = momentTimezone.utcOffset();
  if (momentTimezone.isDST()) {
    // utcOffset will return the offset normalized by DST. If the location
    // is in daylight saving time now, it will be adjusted for that. This is
    // a NAIVE attempt to normalize that by going back 1 hour
    offset -= 60;
  }
  return offset/60;
}

/**
 * Returns the offset range for the given city or region
 * @param location
 */
export function getUtcOffsetForLocation(location: string): number[] | null {
  const timezones = cityTimeZones.findFromCityStateProvince(location);
  if (timezones && timezones.length) {
    // timezones will contain an array of all timezones for all cities inside
    // the given location. For example, if location is a country, this will contain
    // all timezones of all cities inside the country.
    // YOU SHOULD CACHE THE RESULT OF THIS FUNCTION.
    const offsetSet = new Set<number>();
    for (let timezone of timezones) {
      const offset = getNormalizedUtcOffset(timezone.timezone);
      if (offset !== null) {
        offsetSet.add(offset);
      }
    }

    return [...offsetSet].sort((a, b) => a - b);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Unit tests (with Jest)

```
import { getUtcOffsetForLocation } from "../timezone";

describe("timezone", () => {
  describe("getUtcOffsetForLocation", () => {
    it("should work for Lisbon", () => {
      expect(getUtcOffsetForLocation("Lisbon")).toEqual([0]);
    });
    it("should work for Berlin", () => {
      expect(getUtcOffsetForLocation("Berlin")).toEqual([1]);
    });
    it("should work for Germany", () => {
      expect(getUtcOffsetForLocation("Germany")).toEqual([1]);
    });
    it("should work for the United States", () => {
      // when the region has multiple timezones,
      expect(getUtcOffsetForLocation("United States")).toEqual(  [-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4]);
    });
    it("should return null for a non-existing region", () => {
      // when the region has multiple timezones,
      expect(getUtcOffsetForLocation("Blablabla")).toEqual(  null);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use toLocaleTimeString() to find out the time of a particular city of a aprticular country , For example i want to determine the current time in 24 hour of India , so run this script

```
`let indianTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", 
   {timeZone:'Asia/Kolkata',timestyle:'full',hourCycle:'h24'})
   console.log(indianTime)`
```

similarly for time of Dhaka/Bangladesh we can do the same

```
`let bangladeshTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", 
{timeZone:'Asia/Dhaka',timestyle:'full',hourCycle:'h24'})
console.log(bangladeshTime)`
```

here i used a parameter en-Us to get the standard time format

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getTimeOffset(country = 'America/New_York', summerTime = false) {
    let date = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), summerTime ? 6 : 11, 1);
    let wordTime = new Date(date.toISOString().substr(0, 19)).getTime();
    let localTime = new Date(date.toLocaleString('en', { timeZone: country })).getTime();

    return (wordTime - localTime) / 1000 / 60;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TimeZoneOffset :

```js
var d = new Date()
alert(d.getTimezoneOffset());
```

toLocaleTimeString() : This converts time to the local.

```js
var d = new Date();
alert(d.toLocaleTimeString());
```

Using a library: [refer](http://joshowens.me/dealing-with-timezones-in-javascript/), [Auto Time zone detection](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/) & [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: ok.. TimeZoneOffset would do it based on time zones & toLocaleTimeString would convert to local format. But then again he wouldn't get the offset.

Answer (score -3):

There is no default method. Although, there are few ways you can do it easily using the same `getTimeZoneOffSet` method. One such tutorial is here. http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/

```
function calcTime(city, offset) {

// create Date object for current location
d = new Date();

// convert to msec
// add local time zone offset 
// get UTC time in msec
utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

// create new Date object for different city
// using supplied offset
nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

// return time as a string
return "The local time in " + city + " is " + nd.toLocaleString();

}
```

Note that this function requires you to pass the difference from GMT manually. You can use your code behind to get that parameter.